# Smooth the edges in between

Tags: modeling

I want to smooth the edges between without using auto smooth because I want to 3d print it.

I tried to bevel the edges but its kinda working and its not very practical How can I add more geometry with more edges to make it smooth?

[image: how to make it smooother]

Comment: Hi :). Depending on your topology, you could use Subdivision Modifier. If you have n-gons, beveling manually is probably the way.